# Creating ctag DB gives "permission denied" error on git-bash (MS Windows)

Tags: microsoft-windows, bash, ctags

I am a Linux user (world was pretty neat; less to no headache)-- I've been using vim with cscope to wade through huge code-base....... And for some reason, now I have to use windows machine, here are the things I do have on my PC

`git-bash`; downloaded Emacs (I start to love it); and within the Emacs package has `ctags.exe`.

So, I am trying to create the tag file from git-bash

```
~/Downloads/emacs-26.3-x86_64/bin/ctags.exe -R *
```

The tag file gets created, but it skips the source code present in the directories, after running the above command I get

```
bin: Permission denied
contrib: Permission denied
crypto: Permission denied
doc: Permission denied
etc: Permission denied
games: Permission denied
gnu: Permission denied
include: Permission denied
initrd: Permission denied
lib: Permission denied
libexec: Permission denied
nrelease: Permission denied
sbin: Permission denied
```

Really not sure what I am doing wrong here-- even ran `git-bash` as an administrator, tried creating tag file from `cmd` by running it as an admin, yet no luck-- same issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Thanks to `Eli Zaretskii<eliz@gnu.org>`, Gist: ctags on windows won't work on directories.

> You are invoking 'ctags' incorrectly: it needs a list of file names to
>   open and scan.  You used the wildcard "*" which matches all the files,
>   including the directories, and 'ctags' on Windows cannot open and scan
>   directories, only files.
>
> What you probably want is this instead:
>
> $ find . -name '*.[chm]' -o -name '*.el' |
>   ~/Downloads/emacs-26.3-x86_64/bin/ctags -
>
> (This assumes you have a GNU 'find' command reachable from the
>   git-bash where you run this.)

Also found this https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags manual, which I ignored initially, because I though when used the switch `-R` * ctags can recur on directories and build DB out of files, but it wasn't the case and the error it reported `Permission denied` also added more confusions to the puzzle.

Comment: ctags should have `-e` option, quoted from ctags documentation, it "Enable etags mode, which will create a tag file for use with the Emacs editor"

Comment: How does it either relate to the question or the answer?

Comment: The original cli `find . -name '.[chm]' -o -name '.el' | ~/Downloads/emacs-26.3-x86_64/bin/ctags -` can NOT create tags file Emacs can parse. You missed the `-e` option.